# How to use Firefox Firebug on Sub-Menus

Tags: firefox, firebug, firefox-addon

How to use Firefox Firebug on Superfish v1.4.8 Vertical Menu sample but on the sub-menus not the top menu.

[Superfish Menu](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples)

I basically want to be able to freeze Firebug on a sub-menu selection to process but unsure how to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a breakpoint within the menu's javascript handling code to abort processing before any of the mouse-out or "hide the menu" type code is executed, which would leave the menu in the open state for you to inspect. You do that via the 'Script' tab in Firebug and right-clicking on the code line(s) you wish to break on.