# How do I use firebug to see what code collapses a menu?

Tags: javascript, css, firebug

Is it possible to use `Firebug` or similar to determine what piece of javascript caused a specific action?

Example, I am using a bootstrap template that was purchased, and it has a dropdown menu which disappears on click. I want to know what is causing the menu to disappear (such as where in the code) so that I can see how it works and try and remove this functionality.

Comment: Nothing at all to do with `PHP`, so removing that tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Firefox Firebug on Sub-Menus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363011/how-to-use-firefox-firebug-on-sub-menus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the `HTML` tab, right-click on the menu element, and select one or more of the **Break on** options. Then run your application, and when something happens to the element, it will go to the line in the Javascript that caused it.